# Ajudem me a fazer paste!

Tags: php, html

Bom, galera que programa php, estou desenvolvendo um site...
Mais estou com um problema:

```
$linhas = "";

function adcionar_linha($linha) {
$linhas .= $linha."%0D%0A";
}

function criar_paste() {
$curl_ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://paste.ee/api");
curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0");
curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'key=CENSURADO&description=AUTO DaviDEV&paste=Paste gerado pelos sistemas DaviDEV!%0D%0A%0D%0A' . $linhas .'&encrypted=0&expire=0&format=json');
$dadosSite = curl_exec($curl_ch);  
return json_decode($dadosSite)->{'paste'}->{'link'};
}
```

Aí quando eu chamo esta api:

```
adcionar_linha("teste");
echo 'Seu paste: '.criar_paste();
```

E o resultado é: https://paste.ee/p/iFW59

ME AJUDEM!!

Comment: O que você queria que acontecesse, e o que está acontecendo de diferente?

Comment: Eu boto pra adicionar uma linha( a linha "teste" )
E depois quando vou ver a paste a linha não está lá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está passando `$linhas` para a função.

Isso deve resolver:

```
function adcionar_linha( $linha, $linhas ) {
   $linhas .= $linha."%0D%0A";
   return $linhas;
}
function criar_paste( $linhas ) {
    $curl_ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://paste.ee/api");
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0");
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'key=CENSURADO&description=AUTO DaviDEV&paste=Paste gerado pelos sistemas DaviDEV!%0D%0A%0D%0A' . $linhas .'&encrypted=0&expire=0&format=json');
    $dadosSite = curl_exec($curl_ch);  
    return json_decode($dadosSite)->{'paste'}->{'link'};
}
```

E na chamada:

```
$linhas = "";
adcionar_linha( "teste", $linhas );
echo 'Seu paste: '.criar_paste( $linhas );
```

Notar que estamos passando `$linhas` para as duas funções.

### Usando `global`

Uma outra saída seria declarar `$linhas` como `global`, mas é uma solução porca, pois se vai usar funções, não faz tanto sentido elas dependerem de dados externos:

```
$linhas = "";
function adcionar_linha($linha) {
    global $linhas;
    $linhas .= $linha."%0D%0A";
}
function criar_paste() {
    global $linhas;
    $curl_ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://paste.ee/api");
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0");
    curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'key=CENSURADO&description=AUTO DaviDEV&paste=Paste gerado pelos sistemas DaviDEV!%0D%0A%0D%0A' . $linhas .'&encrypted=0&expire=0&format=json');
    $dadosSite = curl_exec($curl_ch);  
    return json_decode($dadosSite)->{'paste'}->{'link'};
}
adcionar_linha("teste");
echo 'Seu paste: '.criar_paste();
```

### Sanitizando os dados com `urlencode()`:

Em ambos os casos, compensa fazer esta alteração para evitar problemas:

```
curl_setopt($curl_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'key=CENSURADO&description=AUTO DaviDEV&
paste=Paste gerado pelos sistemas DaviDEV!%0D%0A%0D%0A'.urlencode($linhas).'&
encrypted=0&expire=0&format=json');
```

(as quebras de linha são só para facilitar a leitura).

O `urlencode()` serve para você não ter problemas se mandar algo com caracteres especiais para o paste:

```
adcionar_linha( 'um=dois&tres');
```

Comment: Funcionou!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Ainda bem... :)